# Bootstrap carousel transition glitch

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with bootstrap carousel. I added custom controls and I styled them according to design, but when I am clicking next slide the previous image disappears leaving white space in the middle.

I edited the bootstrap.css where I changed the .carousel-caption and I added some custom css for the buttons.

Here are the test page: http://valters.me/b/

And I managed to take a screenshot: http://d.pr/i/yGzY

Comment: Or maybe you could suggest alternative carousel.

Comment: Try adding a height and width to your images.

Comment: @shakabra it doesn't matter, it also glitches with just html in it.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2647

Comment: @shakabra Read it, but it won't help as I need captions. Maybe you could suggest some alternative?

Comment: It's not best practice to directly edit the bootstrap css files. You should just add a custom css file which is loaded after the bootstrap ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the transition css from the .carousel-control.left and .carousel-control.right that seems to fix the problem.

Tested in FF and Chrome.

Comment: although this works I can't figure out why? what do the controls have to do with the item transitions?

Answer (score 4):

I tried removing properties from .left and .right, but it didn't solve it for me. The solve I came up with was speeding up the transition. Bootstrap's default is .6s ease-in-out, .5 seemed to do the trick for me. Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.carousel-inner>.item{
   /*disables white flash*/
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: -o-transform .5s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Added this as a backup because white is waaaaay more noticable than black:

```
.carousel-inner{
/*just incase the flash (style above) comes back*/
   background: #000;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Strange enough, 4.0.0 is out but the carousel is still sometimes laggy. Mine was jumping-glithcing when sliding on Firefox(Chrome is fine). 
Tho, I had to add this to .carousel-inner>.item as well:    
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
backface-visibility: visible !important;

Comment: This didn't fix it for me, but the black background sure is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

For bootstrap 4 this worked for me.
In your .css:

```
.carousel { overflow: hidden; }
.carousel-item { overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, someone previously had put a **position: absolute** on the **img** tag inside the carousel. Removing it did helped.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked:

```css
.carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
            backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

Bootstrap Version: 3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

i tried other solutions but only this worked on FF.

```
.carousel-item {backface-visibility: visible;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue with bootstrap 5.0.2 and react-bootstrap 1.6.1.

I was able to come up with a solution by modifying the .css styles which are being applied.

Add this to your custom .css file to override default bootstrap.css

```
carousel-item-next{
  transition: transform 0s ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-item-prev{
    transition: transform 0s ease-in-out;
}
.carousel-item-left {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.carousel-item-right {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```